# C appending two strings

Tags: c

I'm beginning with C and now I want to append two char * together. I wrote this method for this problem:

```
char * strappend(char * x, char * n) {
  size_t xlen = strlen(x);
  size_t nlen = strlen(n);
  char * c = realloc(x, xlen + nlen + 1);
  strncat(c, n, nlen + 1);
  return c;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
char * buffer = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(buffer, "What");
buffer = strappend(buffer, "up");
printf("%s", buffer);
free (buffer);
```

Now I am not sure if strncat requires the + 1, which I thought was needed for the \0? Is this true and is my own method error free?

Comment: Have you looked at `man strncat`? Also, why do you need `strappend` if you're going to call a C library routine such as `strncat` or `strcat` anyway?

Comment: This function is not gonna work the way you are currently using it. You should call it like `buffer = strappend(buffer, "up");`, since `realloc` may modify the pointer.

Comment: Sorry that is what I'm doing copy/paste mistake but thanks for the notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. realloc() is an expensive operation. You don't wan't to use it often. In this case, depending on the structure and requirements of your code, it may be better to make sure that the "buffer" has enough space for the concatenated string
2. If you can accomplish my advise in (1), you don't need your strappend() function. Just use strncat() within your code (with proper range checks of course)
3. If you can't allocate space for "buffer" beforehand and decide to continue using realloc(), here is a tip: in strappend() function you already know the length of the strings. Thus you don't have to call strncat(). You can simply call a memcpy() which is guaranteed to be faster. So, instead of:

   ```
   strncat(c, n, nlen + 1);
   ```

   call:

   ```
   memcpy(c + xlen, n, nlen);
   c[xlen + nlen] = '\0';
   ```

And a direct answer to your question is "no, you don't need the +1 there". Check the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strncat.html).

Comment: Very nice! I understand that realloc is expensive but it is needed because I do not know the size of the string beforehand (question just has an example). But I will definitely try out the memcpy!. But in your answer you use strncat with the + 1 or is this just copy paste?

Answer (score 1):

[strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/): "Appends the first num characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null-character."  So there is no need to add extra 1, you considered it in realloc.

BTW, strlen(0) will crash - don't you consider safe function?

Comment: Thank you, I do not know a safe strlen function

Comment: I meant your function to be safe - to check params x, n on == 0

Comment: Added a check: if (x == NULL || n == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

Answer (score 0):

sprintf is very convenient:

```
const char* st = "START";
const char* en = " END";
char s[100];
sprintf(s, "%s%s", st, en);
```

Comment: An overkill. `memcpy()` is enough

Answer (score 0):

If `n` refers to a `0`-terminated array (which can be implied as `strlen()` is called on `n`), you can simply use

```
  strcat(c, n);
```

---

Also this function provokes undefined behaviour if getting passed in `NULL` for `x` or `n`. Take care of these cases by doing:

```
  size_t xlen = x ?strlen(x) :0;
  size_t nlen = n ?strlen(n) :0;
```

---

Also^2 mind this case when concatenating like so:

```
  if (n)
  {
    strat(c, n);
  }
```

---

Finally you might consider helping the compiler by telling it what is constant in the function by defining the function's parameters alike:

```
char * strappend(const char * x, const char * n)
```